# Iterating on results up to a condition with Project Reactor in Java

Tags: java, project-reactor

I need to iterate on results from a datastore until I find that no result matches a condition I have, using Flux and/or Mono from Project Reactor. I have a solution, but it uses errors to control flow. I really feel like there should be a cleaner solution, but if there is, I can't find it. Is there a better way to achieve what I want than this:

```java
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mono<String> mono = Mono.fromSupplier(new AtomicInteger(0)::incrementAndGet)
                .map(count -> "FooBar " + count)
                .flatMap(string -> searchExisting(string)
                        .flatMap(exists -> Mono.<String>error(KeyExistsException::new))
                        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(string)))
                .retry(t -> t instanceof KeyExistsException);

        System.out.println("Result: " + mono.block());
    }

    private static Mono<String> searchExisting(String test) {
        System.out.println("In searchExisting: " + test);
        return Mono.fromCompletionStage(getCompletableFuture(test));
    }

    private static final List<String> available = asList(
            "FooBar 1", "FooBar 2", "FooBar 3", "FooBar 4", "FooBar 5"
    );

    private static CompletableFuture<String> getCompletableFuture(String test) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("In CompletableFuture: " + test);

            if (available.contains(test)) {
                return test;
            }

            System.out.println("Found no entry");
            return null;
        });
    }
}

class KeyExistsException extends RuntimeException {

}
```

I've tried using a `Flux.fromStream(Stream.iterate(1, x -> x + 1))` and going from there, but in this case, I still need the error-based flow control and I can't control the rate at which the `Flux` emits data, which means that I get a lot of accesses to the datastore when I'm only looking for a few, up until I find the missing value.

This feels like a common enough use-case. What am I missing?

--- EDIT ---

From Bartosz's suggestion, an alternative implementation would look like this:

```java
Mono<String> mono = Flux.fromStream(Stream.iterate(1, x -> x + 1))
                .map(count -> "FooBar " + count)
                .flatMap(newKey -> Mono.zip(Mono.just(newKey), searchExisting(newKey)))
                .takeUntil(tuple -> !tuple.getT2().isPresent())
                .map(Tuple2::getT1)
                .last();
```

which is a *lot* nicer, except that it doesn't provide any control over how many events are emitted by the `Flux` - you get a *lot* of attempts to find the right value, far more than you need, because `takeUntil` doesn't make the `Flux` lazy...

Comment: Have you tried use `Flux.takeUntil()`? https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#takeUntil-java.util.function.Predicate-

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I've updated the question. It's a much nicer approach, but unfortunately doesn't work for me because it doesn't limit the number of accesses to the datastore to the minimum that I need to find the right value.

Comment: @AndyB Regarding the update have you added an optional somewhere to the original as you are now using `isPresent()`

Comment: Yes, that’s right - I have a need for the optional in my production code, but I accidentally left it out of the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to using `Optional`s you could combine both your attempts and do something like

```
    Mono<String> mono =  Mono.fromSupplier(new AtomicInteger(0)::incrementAndGet)
            .map(count -> "FooBar " + count)
            .flatMap(newKey -> Mono.zip(Mono.just(newKey), 
                                           searchExisting(newKey)
                                               .map(Optional::ofNullable)
                                               .defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty())))
            .repeat()
            .takeUntil(tuple -> tuple.getT2().isEmpty())
            .map(Tuple2::getT1)
            .last();

    System.out.println("Result: " + mono.block());
```

The major issue with what you are trying to do is that empty `Mono`s are ignored by pretty much everything bar `switchIfEmpty()` meaning none of the operators such as `takeUntil` will ever even see them.

Normally this is what you would want, but in your case you want to act on the empty Mono. 
Wrapping it an `Optional` allows it to still be processed.

Comment: Thanks. `repeat()` may be just what I was looking for. I’ll give it a go and see what falls out.